# Alternative Bullet Propellant That Produces Inert Gasses

Tags: weapons

Recently, I asked a question([previous question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/210659/sodium-azide-for-bullet-propellant/210660#210660)
) about the viability of sodium azide as an alternative bullet propellant, and besides the fact that it seems like ignition is mostly electric(temps of 300C are needed), it has several drawbacks like producing messy sodium after reacting, as well as the sodium azide being a poison itself. What are alternative bullet propellants that can produce large amounts of inert gas using a smaller primer compared to regular bullets, for hopefully a quieter shot?
Just noting, apparently sodium azide produces a white puff when ignited, so if a propellant has any weird quirks like that, please list them(good for plot purposes/identifying factions).

Comment: If your goal is quiet shot (and you want to preserve things like muzzle velocity), there is little you can gain by changing propellant composition.

Comment: I think you should be more clear about what you are trying to achieve.  People who make guns know all about propellants, and have chosen the ones we use because they are best for the job at had.  If you have a different priorities then others may be optimal, but you need to specify what those priorities are.

Comment: Have you considered compressed air? As early as late XVIII century, Austria employed sharpshooter regiments equipped with Girandoni air rifles. While more fragile, complex and difficult to use than contemporary muzzle loading muskets, those weapons were just as deadly while being considerably more accurate and offered significantly higher rate of fire. Now, this days air rifles can't really compete with standard chemical rifles, but you could certainly make lethal air rifle if needed and it would be quieter than chemical weapon with comparable performance.

Comment: @Miech Not really tbh, my goal was to retain the original bullet form factor with a cartridge with propellant, and a bullet on top. I'm pretty sure that compressed air would required a separate tank, and besides a couple niche airsoft products, I've never seen anymore integrate the compressed air into the cartridge.

Comment: @Dave Sorry for not specifying, I'm looking for the majority of the characteristics of like normal smokeless powder, just more quiet.

Comment: The noise made by a gun has very little to do with the details of the propellant.  It is principally determined by the speed of the bullet and the gasses behind it at the point the bullet leaves the barrel.  You can get any value of those by using more or less of a conventional propellant.  Perhaps look at [silencers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silencer_(firearms))?

Comment: There is also https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn14372-toy-rocket-inspires-variable-speed-bullets/ which, in theory, which was a proposal to use hydrogen+oxygen gas as propellant.  However, it would be similar in structure to an airgun and so does not meet your requirements for a cartridge and also, judging from lack of further development, probably didn't actually work anyway.

Comment: The question and comments focus to an odd degree on the primer. The primer is not what makes guns loud, and there's nothing in particular to gain from making the primer much smaller.

Comment: I just saw this video talking about airbag components, and it seems like Guadine Nitrate was the material settled on that isn't toxic and used for starting jet engines: https://youtu.be/mxHJ3O4iudw?t=1039

Comment: I also found this article from the US government reporting the experiment (I still didn't read to the end): https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/ADA066090

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try the path of the [bombardier beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_beetle#Mechanism_of_defense):

> There are two large glands that open at the tip of the abdomen. Each gland is composed of a thick walled vestibule which contains a mixture of catalases and peroxidases produced by the secretory cells that line the vestibule. Both glands are also made up of a thin-walled and compressible reservoir which contains an aqueous solution of hydroquinones and hydrogen peroxide.
>
> When the beetle feels threatened it opens a valve which allows the aqueous solution from the reservoir to reach the vestibule.
>
> The net reaction  $C_6H_4(OH)_2(aq)+H_2O_2(aq) \to C_6H_4O_2(aq) + H_2O(l)$ is very exothermic, and the released energy raises the temperature of the mixture to near 100 °C, vaporizing about a fifth of it. The resultant pressure buildup forces the entrance valves from the reactant storage chambers to close, thus protecting the beetle's internal organs.
>
> The boiling, foul-smelling liquid is expelled violently through an outlet valve, with a loud popping sound.

Since you are not bound by the constrain of a living organism, you can increase the temperature and the pressure, so that the force on the bullet can be bigger. The only side effect seems to be that the resulting gases are rather smelly.

Comment: Hmm I see, would it just be like a hypergolic reaction, where maybe the primer would rupture the partition between the two chemicals and they would mix and react and on contact?

Answer (score 2):

I am recycling my old answer from here!  [Can combustion light gas guns use metallic hydrogen or something else to retain the compactness of a bullet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/192309/can-combustion-light-gas-guns-use-metallic-hydrogen-or-something-else-to-retain/192399#192399)

If leftovers are not your thing, look away.  But I very much dig

**Cubic gauche nitrogen.**

[image: cubic gauche nitrogen]
http://www.esrf.eu/UsersAndScience/Publications/Highlights/2004/Materials/Mat12

This is trippy stuff, but it is real and people are making it.  Nitrogen likes to be N≡N which is why it is so stable.  High power rocket fuel often puts nitrogen into configurations it likes less, so when it relaxes back into N2 a tremendous amount of energy is released.

Cubic gauche nitrogen is the most powerful of all of them, and [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_nitrogen#Cubic_gauche)

> This cubic-gauche nitrogen is the highest energy non-nuclear material
> and is being investigated for use in explosives and rocket fuel.

Here is a cool article about people making the stuff under ambient temperature and pressure.  If they can do it, people in your world can do it.

[Cubic gauche polymeric nitrogen under ambient conditions](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-01083-5)

> A large amount of energy (2.3 eV per atom) is expected to be released
> upon transforming singly-bonded nitrogen to diatomic triply-bonded
> molecular nitrogen. This chemical energy can be ideally stored during
> the transformation of a triple bond to three single bonds in polymeric
> nitrogen to form a high energy density material1. Consequently,
> single-bonded polymeric nitrogen should be a high energy density
> material with a range of applications as a metal-free “green”
> energetic material, or as a propellant... Here, we describe the
> synthesis and stabilization of polymeric nitrogen in its cubic gauche
> phase under near-ambient conditions employing plasma-enhanced chemical
> vapour deposition which is known to form high pressure phases, such as
> that of diamond at ambient conditions.

Cubic gauche nitrogen has an energy density of 33 kJ/G according to wikipedia.

Comment: I really like this idea! How stable is it when being jostled around(before being fired) and would a normal sized or maybe even smaller than average primer be enough to set it off reliably?